# UISwitch will not connect to @IBAction

Tags: swift, uidatepicker, ibaction, uiswitch

I am creating a local notification system that allows someone to change the time that the local notification gets to them. I have a UIDatePicker and Switch.

I can't connect either of them to @IBActions so that they can perform the notification fireDate time change. It does not show in the pop-up as an option.

How do I get the switch and UIDatePicker to show IBAction?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try to stop and touch up drugging exactly on your existing @IBAction methods

Comment: Have you set both their classes correctly in the `Identity Inspector`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that under module it displays "none". Either you need that to be set to your app, your that class "myDatePicker" doesn't exist in your app.